# Linked list add function results in a segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Calling this value works for the first 2 calls and then causes a segmentation fault.

```
void insert_message(char *id, char *message) {
    if (first_message == NULL) {
        first_message = malloc( sizeof(struct server_message) );
        strcpy(first_message->id, id);
        strcpy(first_message->message, message);
        first_message->next_msg = NULL;
    } else {
        struct server_message *curr_msg = first_message;

        while (curr_msg != NULL) {
            curr_msg = curr_msg->next_msg;
        }

        curr_msg->next_msg = malloc( sizeof(struct server_message) );
        strcpy (curr_msg->next_msg->id, id);
        strcpy (curr_msg->next_msg->message, message);
        curr_msg->next_msg->next_msg = NULL;
    }
}
```

First Message and Server Message struct:

```
// used to store messages.
struct server_message {
    char message[80];
    char id[80];
    struct server_message *next_msg;
};

//head of the list
static struct server_message *first_message = NULL;
```

Comment: while (curr_msg != NULL) ---->  while (curr_msg->next_msg != NULL)

Comment: Instead of `curr_msg != NULL` use `curr_msg->next_msg != NULL`

Comment: Debugger.......................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop finishes when `curr_msg == NULL` holds. Calling `curr_msg->next_msg = malloc( sizeof(struct server_message) );` will fail since you cannot dereference `NULL`. Hence do the following:

```
while (curr_msg->next_msg != NULL) {
    curr_msg = curr_msg->next_msg;
}
// curr_msg is now the last node in your list
```

Answer (score -1):

```
As per your loop , after came out of loop , you have to allocate memory for curr_msg & you have to fill the necessary info in that curr_msg structure. Because in your curr_msg structure ,already you stored the link to next_msg  

so you have to modify your code like below

while (curr_msg != NULL) 
{
            curr_msg = curr_msg->next_msg;
}

curr_msg = malloc( sizeof(struct server_message) );
strcpy (curr_msg->id, id);
strcpy (curr_msg->message, message);
curr_msg->next_msg = NULL;
```

Comment: Doing so will NOT add the new node to the list!